# ASP.NET Application Pool Recycling Issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf, application-pool, recycle

I have a Web Project setup that has both my WebForms and a WCF service.  I am having an issue where every so often my application seems to recycle and i lose all singleton objects and session values.  It does not appear to be a timeout issue, but maybe a memory leak of some kind.  We can be using the app for a minute or so and then bam it just loses everything.

I have tried monitoring the directory for changes but found no changes to the filesystem at all.  I also put a breakpoint in Application_Error and there are no errors being thrown.

I have been googling for two days trying to resolve this issue.  The application is a direct duplication of a previous project that is working fine.  The one thing I noticed that is different is my last project I used nHibernate for the backend and this project I switched to using Linq to SQL.  I noticed that I wasn't handling the DataContext properly because I was diming an isntance of the DataContext inside my service calls and returning a value before ever disposing or setting the context back to nothing, so I figured it may not be closing.  I tried instead of storing the datacontext in my "repository" class i stored it inside the operationcontext and explicitly dispose it on Application_EndRequest.  That still hasn't resolved the issue.

Anyone have any suggestions or places I should look?

** UPDATE **:  I believe i found my issue.  I have objects that are using EntitySet and i am serializing those objects directly back using a serializable IList property with a linq query returning the list.  When i tried to explicitly dispose of my datacontext before returning the data I am running into issues serializing those EntitySet's now because the datacontext is no longer active.  I am going to try copying the data into a new blank object with regular Lists instead of EntitySet's and see if this will allow me to properly close my datacontext and resolve my issue.

Comment: Just a quick question: Is the above application only one using that App Pool or does it share the pool with another application?

Comment: I assume you've already come across this: [Common reasons why your application pool may unexpectedly recycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx)

Comment: Is it shared hosting or your own web server?

Comment: not shared.  This happens in developement in visual studio as well as deployed onto the server.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that the application pool is being recycled? How do you know?

Comment: Are you spawning threads? Any unhandled exceptions on spawned threads will cause the application to recycle and will not get caught in Application_Error.

Comment: I don't know.  I just know that i lose all singleton objects and all session variables.  I am assuming it is the app pool recycling.

Comment: No threads either.  This is a pretty simple web app that is consuming WCF services via jquery calls.  One thing I do have is a custom Authorization Policy that reads a header i set for an oauth authorization key each time.  it then reads the singleton to ensure the auth token is valid and then adds the roles corresponding.  if nothing is found it simply adds a generalidentity and an empty array of roles.

Comment: fyi this issue existed prior to me implementing oauth

Answer (score 1):

Update is really a different question, but you really should not try and serialize stuff that comes off of an ORM -- lots of potential nightmares. Build yourself some DTOs.

Comment: I've written DTO's and now only DTO's get serialized out.  I am also properly closing the DataContext.  The problem still remains unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS7 Console, select the specific application pool, and select "Recycling..." in the action pane to the left. It's a wizard that lets you define how the application pool recycles, and how it logs the recycle events to the event log (page 2 of the wizard).

Comment: Sorry, i should have made it clear.  It happens with the development web server when I debug it in Visual Studio as well.  It is not a setting in IIS.  I am pretty sure it is a setting in my web.config or possibly an issue with my code.